# error: 'gtk_window_close' undeclared (first use in this function); How can I solve this issue?

Tags: c, gcc, windows-10, gtk3, gnu

#### PROBLEM

I am trying to solve an issue which occurs when I try and compile [this example file](https://www.gtk.org/docs/getting-started/hello-world/):

```c
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void print_hello(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
  g_print ("Hello World\n");
}

static void activate(GtkApplication *app, gpointer user_data)
{
  GtkWidget *window;
  GtkWidget *button;

  window = gtk_application_window_new (app);
  gtk_window_set_title (GTK_WINDOW (window), "Window");
  gtk_window_set_default_size (GTK_WINDOW (window), 200, 200);

  button = gtk_button_new_with_label ("Hello World");
  g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (print_hello), NULL);
  gtk_window_set_child (GTK_WINDOW (window), button);

  gtk_window_present (GTK_WINDOW (window));
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  GtkApplication *app;
  int status;

  app = gtk_application_new ("org.gtk.example", G_APPLICATION_FLAGS_NONE);
  g_signal_connect (app, "activate", G_CALLBACK (activate), NULL);
  status = g_application_run (G_APPLICATION (app), argc, argv);
  g_object_unref (app);

  return status;
}
```

Everything was installed and when I compile with gcc.exe everything works although at the end of compiling I get an issue which is below!

Issue occurs after running this command:

```
gcc.exe -IC:/gtk_32bit/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/gtk_32bit/include/cairo -IC:/gtk_32bit/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/gtk_32bit/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/gtk_32bit/include/cairo -IC:/gtk_32bit/include/pixman-1 -IC:/gtk_32bit/include -IC:/gtk_32bit/include/freetype2 -IC:/gtk_32bit/include -IC:/gtk_32bit/include/libpng15 -IC:/gtk_32bit/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/gtk_32bit/include/libpng15 -IC:/gtk_32bit/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/gtk_32bit/lib/glib-2.0/include -v hello-world-gtk.c -LC:/gtk_32bit/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl -o hello-world-gtk.exe
```

I created the command above from the command below which does not run when I try to use the command below:

```
gcc.exe "pkg-config.exe --cflags gtk+-3.0" -o hello-world-gtk hello-world-gtk.c "pkg-config.exe --libs gtk+-3.0"
```

I also noticed that the web site link above had the command above previously although today I noticed they changed the command above to the command below:

```
gcc -o hello-world-gtk hello-world-gtk.c "pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk4"
```

Which could be the reason why It doesn't work but I am assuming that the previous command should work just as the current command which Is the updated command thats on the web site now.

#### ERROR

```
hello-world-gtk.c:27:60: error: 'gtk_window_close' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'gtk_window_move'?
   27 |   g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_window_close), window);
```

#### Assumption

I am using make.exe. I also tried to do the gcc.exe command without make. Both ways cause an issue which is above!~ What I do not know is what the issue is! If it is related to missing libraries or include files which have not been located in the process of compiling with or without make! What I am curious to know is if it is related to a missing library file or include file. What file it is that I am missing would be a question I will need to solve and do not know how to solve.

Comment: Do you have `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` in your code?

Comment: Yes I do. That also is not the issue.

Comment: you need to show the code where you call the function `gtk_window_close` (better show some code, as without the code is very difficult to guess anything)

Comment: Its all the exact code from the link I don't understand how the link does not provide code that is functional as an example code to compile. Everything should just compile to show the example! https://www.gtk.org/docs/getting-started/hello-world/

Comment: I did everything that was explained that needed to be completed to see the example program run! Although I can't get such example provided to run just to make sure that everything was installed correctly! Its really a disappointment for a beginner to try and learn and also make sure everything was completed as was needed to start and learn how to use GTK3 or GTK4 API and use GTK!

Answer (score -1):

The compiler error:

```
hello-world-gtk.c:27:60: error: 'gtk_window_close' undeclared (first use in this function); did you mean 'gtk_window_move'?
   27 |   g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (gtk_window_close), window);
```

is telling you that it doesn't know what kind of object is `gtk_window_close`, as you pass it to a function (supossedly it is a pointer, but the compiler must know it is the pointer to a function, the types and number of parameters and the return value it is)

The `gtk_window_close` function should match the parameter list with the requirements of `G_CALLBACK` and the compiler cannot do that, because the appropiate header file is not `#include`d.

You can dig in the include file `<gtk/gtk.h>` to see where it is this function defined.  You can consult this page for more info: [`GtkWindow` - `gtk_window_close`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWindow.html#gtk-window-close)